# jquery ajax post not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a little problem with jQuery ajax.
I want to send a POST to a .php file and afterwards change the current URL. I tried the following code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {'username': "STRING"},
        timeout: 1000,
        complete: function(){
            window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1/sample/another.php';
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

So, as I can see in the chrome developer tools Network tab, no POST is executed. Although the URL changed to another.php

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong or how I can solve this issue?

Comment: try changing complete to success...

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer tools console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never see the POST. cause the url changes and remember the another.php hasn't made any AJAX requests! so you'll never find anything there. try changing the JS code in the success method to something like an alert to know if it works! and maybe then you'll find the POST method in the console!

Comment: If issue still persists, try using Mozilla firebug and live Http Header to further debug the issues.

Comment: Well, you were right... The POST was sent and executed well, but I don't see it. after replace the complete part with an alert() I saw the post... Thanks allot!

Comment: No problems! glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

use success instead of complete

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {'username': "STRING"},
        timeout: 1000,
        success : function(){
            window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1/sample/another.php';
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think he mentioned that the url changes. Which means the AJAX part works. He's just confused regarding the developer tools not showing the POST request being made. Which is quite obvious. Since the URL changed, he's now on another page which hasn't made any requests. Hence the empty network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use .done() as well. You may also think about scoping this inside a self executing function instead of a window.onload event.

```
    (function($){

    // Make an object for your param values. 
    var ajaxData = {
        username: 'STRING',
        anotherParam: 'STRING',
        andanotherParam: 'STRING',
        yetanotherParam: 'STRING'
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: ajaxData
    }).done(function(){
        window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1/sample/another.php';
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });

}(jQuery));
```